# Is there any way I can detect a crash (Vehicle Accident) from a user's device(Mobile) and if so how can I implement it in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, crash, gps

I'm trying to build an application that detects vehicle crashes in react native. So far i discovered how I can determine speed of the device and track the trip. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use react native sensors https://react-native-sensors.github.io/ to get accelerometer data and monitor sudden decrease on it, but you will get a lot of false positive.

Comment: Thanks Francesco, Even though using Accelerometer Sounded like a good Solution it gets triggered in almost every scenario involving sudden brakes and stuff thus, defeating the whole purpose.

Comment: You can add also excessive sounds